# Windows loses the connection to the monitors when putting them asleep

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, external-display, lg-monitor

I have a new setup with 2 external monitors (LG 32" 4K) on a Lenovo T14 laptop PC under Windows 10. In the display settings the built-in monitor is disconnected when the 2 external monitors are plugged, and I've set a 10mn inactivity delay before turning off the monitors.

The problem: when the monitors are turned off by Windows, it seems that the they also get disconnected. There is the OSD (not Windows) message on the screens "No signal: entering the power saving mode shortly". And when I resume the activity:

- I can briefly see that the the built-in is active, before the external ones get reconnected
- all the window dispositions on the secondary monitor (connected with Display port) have been lost, and all the windows have been moved to the primary monitor (connected with USB-C)

I tried playing with the monitor setting, without success.

My previous setup with 2 old HP monitors (both in Display Port) and a Dell laptop did not have this behavior, the window disposition was kept on both screens.

Any suggestion ?